# Where to cache a file for a Eclipse RCP-plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, workspace

I'm developing a plugin for an Eclipse-RCP-Application. Now I would like to cache a file (as I don't wan't to access the internet, whenever it's needed). This file should be accessible even after relaunching the application. Where would be the best place for it?

I thought about the workspace/.metadata folder. But I'm not sure if that is the right place and how to retrieve the location information. This should work, but I did not yet manage to find `ResourcesPlugin`

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

Can anybody give me a hint for the best place to store such a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want users to see the file use the plug-in 'state location'. You get this using:

```java
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin's Bundle

IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

The plugin's state location is a folder which is part of the workspace meta data (`.metadata/.plugins/plugin id` to be exact).

You can put whatever you like in this folder. It is up to your plugin to manage this data.

You can get the `Bundle` in various ways, such as:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

or

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

Note: The code you mention in your question would put the file in the workspace and it would be visible to the user. `ResourcesPlugin` is in the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I need!